# Last Delimiter in CSV file with FileHelpers

Tags: filehelpers

I must develop a **CSV-Export** with 57 columns.

After the last column i need the delimiter and then the LFCR.

**Example:**

Now i have

```
aaaa;bbbb;cccc;dddd
```

But i need

```
aaaa;bbbb;cccc;dddd;
```

Which attribute can control this?

Comment: Can't you just add another empty value to your records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can do this with an attribute, but you can with the AfterWriteRecord event

example

```
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<Record>();
    records.Add(new Record() { A = "aaaa", B = "bbbb", C = "cccc", D = "dddd" });

    var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Record>();
    engine.HeaderText = engine.GetFileHeader();

    engine.AfterWriteRecord += AfterWriteEvent;
    engine.WriteFile("output.csv", records);                
}

void AfterWriteEvent(EngineBase engine, AfterWriteEventArgs<Record> e)
{
    e.RecordLine += ";" ;
}

[FileHelpers.DelimitedRecord(";")] 
public class Record
{    
    public string A;
    public string B;
    public string C;
    public string D;
}
```

outputs

```
A;B;C;D 
aaaa;bbbb;cccc;dddd;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add a dummy field at the end of your class. You can mark it `[FieldOptional]` so that it is not required if you use the same class for import.